# make android HomeAsUp icon disappear on demand

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

In my android app, in the Action Bar, next to the `<` image is an icon. I want to make it invisible/gone ondemand dynamically. How do I do that? The icon is actually defined as follows (this should help you realize where in the action bar I am talking about).

```
<style name="MyAppName.LogoTheme.LogoActionBar" parent="MyAppName.Theme.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:displayOptions">showHome|homeAsUp</item>
    <item name="android:icon">@drawable/my_icon</item>
```

I tried the following, but nothing.

```
this.getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
this.getActionBar().setLogo(null);
this.getActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, call `setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false)` and `setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)` on your ActionBar.

Comment: That was sooooo much help.